# spark: class not found exception

Tags: maven, apache-spark

I'm getting class not found exception when running the spark2-submit command in the console. Can anyone please suggest me what could be the error.

[image]

```
spark2-submit --class spark.FirstQuestion.SingleLookupFilter \
              --master yarn --deploy-mode client \
              --name aws_spark \
              --conf "spark.app.id=spark_aws_run" \
              FirstQuestion-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar \
              /user/ec2-user/spark_assignment/input/yellow_tripdata_* \
              /user/ec2-user/spark_assignment/spark_output/single_row_lookup_SparkRDD
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of text files, those are just harder to read and search won't find them

Answer (score 0):

It does not complain about "class not found". It complains about class `SingleLookupFilter` not having the `main(String[])` method, which makes the class a valid entry point to the program. Check if the method is there, if in doubt paste the code of the class here.